# 2nd phone interview for international job - how to ask to see the workplace?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

This is an IT support job.

So I've had a first (pretty casual) phone call (20mins) with the head of IT and a few co-workers last week, and I've got a 2nd phone interview later today with HR.

The guys working there seems all very friendly, but I really want to see the workplace in person and meet the people who I'd be working with before accepting the job (if I get offered it after this interview).

> I'm happy to cover travel costs, but just wondering how should I bring this up, should I talk about it in the 2nd interview today, or wait till I get an offer?

I live in New Zealand and the job is in Australia (I'm relocating there), and flying there and back costs about 290USD (400NZD).

Comment: Regardless of what happens, don't relocate yet during your probation period. Pick some temporary place to stay.

Comment: How did this turn out?

Comment: Wow there's been quite a bit of activity here since I was last here. But I was offered the job, and talked about visiting the office which they were open to before I signed, though they wanted to know if I was going to accept before the visit. But after some thinking I decided to decline the offer for multiple reasons. It was also my first interview in years, and my 2nd real one since ever (I was really lucky in getting my first job). But it did give me some good experience, I'm still stumped as to why they offered me the job, I thought I did quite terrible in the interviews...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a good chance there may be a final in office interview.  If there isn't and they offer you the job, you can make meeting your acceptance conditional upon meeting your co-workers.  I'd suggest a fly in, meet the office, sign papers then start the next week.

If given the offer I would say something like:

> That's very exciting.  I'd like to see the workspace and meet the people I'll be working with before we finalize everything.  Can I come into the office and we can finalize arrangements in person?

They would probably also like to meet you in person, so it's probably a win-win and a good 400 NZD investment on their part.

Comment: They want the chosen candidate to start straight away after they decide end of next week, so kinda sounded like this was the last interview. Also it's a junior level job so I expect they have lots of good local candidates too, so was assuming I would pay for the flights. (also thanks for the great answer!)

Comment: @Mint This request seems very reasonable to me, especially if you are willing to pay the travel costs. You sound confident in your idea that you'd like to see the office and meet people before accepting the job - I think that sounds great. Keep that same confidence even if they offer you the job and try to rush you into it next week.

Comment: How is this different from accepting the offer and resigning after few days?

Comment: @Tymski There is a difference between breaking a contract, signed in poor faith and a deal falling apart last minute.  Deals fall apart and that's a normal risk of business but you should never sign something without expecting to follow through on what you signed.

Comment: @Myles I was thinking about taking advantage of a probationary period - not about doing anything against the rules.

Answer (score 0):

There usually is time in an interview where the interviewer(s) explain the next steps of the recruitment process. I would ask about seeing the office in person at this time.

If the issue is never raised and an offer is presented I can see these choices:

- ask if there is a page where you can see the office and team members;
- ask to see the office and meet people before you accept. A short email with this request is as good as anything;
- accept the offer and take the risk. You should already have some idea about the people from the phone interviews. What you see and feel during a staged tour may not represent your experience after joining the company.
  EDIT: Clarification, I'm talking about **probationary period** when the notice is usually very short (a day or a week), **not** about braking a contract and just walking off the job.

Comment: I believe the probationary period was set to 6 months... though I may have understood this wrong. I believe it's usually 3 months, here in New Zealand. Maybe 6 is the standard in Aus.